# How to return elements using for loop within a function?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Below is the given list of strings from which I am trying to find the strings which contains the substring.
Output is obtained perfectly without using functions. However when function is used, it does return only 1 substring and not the list of strings containing the substring.

```
L = ['dog', 'dodge', 'cat', 'cattle']

sub_string = str(input("Enter the substring: "))

for i in range(len(L)):
    v = L[i].find(sub_string, 0,100)
    if v >= 0:
        print(L[i])           #returns all the strings containing the substring very well.

def String_find(sub_string):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if sub_string in L[i]:         
            return L[i]        #returns only 'dog' or 'cat' if substring is entered whereas 
                               #'dog','dodge' 
                               #or 'cat','cattle' is expected.

Total = String_find(sub_string)
#Output is obtained perfectly without using functions however when function is used it does return         
#only 1 substring and not the list of strings containing the substring.
```

Comment: `return`  returns immediately, so the first match will trigger the exit of the function. You may be lookiing for `yield`, or to return a list that you fill with matches.

Comment: `return` will cause the loop to exit. So as soon as a match is found, it exits from the loop.

Comment: Thanks @L3viathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You maybe want to do this:

```
def string_find(sub):
    return [item for item in L if sub in item]

items = string_find(sub_string)
print(items)
```

Comment: Most optimal solution